# HP Proliant DL360 G6 Maximum Logical Drives

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sas

I have an HP Proliant DL360 G6 server with 8 HD bays.  Currently I have the first two bays working with ESXi and I'm just running RAID 0 on a single drive.  This is not a production machine.  It has a P410i Controller.  I'm trying to add a third drive to machine and when I go into the controller menu at boot time and select "Create Logical Drive" it says I've reached the max of 2 logical drives.  I was under the impression I could many more logical drives than just 2?  I'm not a server admin by any means, so this is definitely not my strength, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this issue](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03484167), you need to have a cache memory module on your RAID controller in order to have more than 2 logical drives on a Smart Array P410 setup.

See: 
[HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 Server - Unable to Create More Than 2 Logical Drives](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03484167)

Comment: Damn - beat me to it by seconds :)

Comment: something like this?  http://www.amazon.com/HP-Flash-Backed-Write-534562-B21/dp/B007BG7KN6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1436550164&sr=8-1&keywords=534562-B21

Comment: @KyleRogers Exactly. That's what you'll need. Look on eBay as well.