# Configure more than two logical drives in an HP ProLiant Gen8 server?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've a server HP Proliant dl380 gen 8. I've got 2 RAID 1 drives (each having 2 HDDs (300gb) in a mirror). I've now come to put 4 extra physical disks into the server and it won't let me create the logical disks for the 2 new drives. I want to create an other new logical drive for thoses 4 physical drives

When I try to add them from the RAID utility (F8 during boot) I get a message saying ORCA can't handle any more logical drives, and that I should use the array config utility to add them. I tried using the array config to add them but can't see how to do it. The disks are both picked up and labeled "un-allocated" but I can't find any way to allocate them.

Comment: Has your disk controller got any FBWC?

Answer (score 1):

Press `F10` at POST to enter Intelligent Provisioning and use the [HP SSA utility](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5409020) to configure your array.

The BIOS ORCA utility is not really supposed to be used for anything other than basic functions.

---

If this doesn't work, you have another issue. See: [HP Proliant DL360 G6 Maximum Logical Drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/704921/hp-proliant-dl360-g6-maximum-logical-drives)

Comment: I used the HP SSA utility, but it is the same issue i can not create more than two logical drives.

Comment: @MouelleMarc See my edit. You should have provided more information about your _specific_ server model, controller, cache, etc.